# vuex: set default values from async function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, store, vuex

I have the following store:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        someProp: someAsyncFn().then(res => res),
        ...
    },
    ...
})
```

Somehow it looks like `someProp` isn't waiting for the values to be resolved. Is this bad practise? Should I set an empty object as default and update the state via mutation on load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be doing it like this :

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        someProp: null
        ...
    },
    mutations:{
        initializeSomeProp: (state, payload) => {
            state.someProp = payload;
        }
    },
    actions:{
        asyncSomeProp: ({commit}) => {
            someAsyncFn().then(res => commit('initializeSomeProp', res))
        } 
    }
})
```

Asynchronous functionality should be handled by actions. You can use this action `asyncSomeProp` and the commit a mutation `initializeSomeOrop` by passing the `res` which you get in your async callback as a payload parameter.

Then if you want to initialize your `someProp` in some component then you can dispatch your `asyncSomeProp` action in created lifecycle hook of that component as follows:

```
created(){
    this.$store.dispatch('asyncSomeProp');
}
```